# How to retrieve the value from an array without index

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[["Django UnChainers","AA-24010"],["General","AA-26191"]]
```

I have one array in above form. I want to retrieve all the value with prefix **AA** (which are in the second position). Is there any way where I can fetch the value by passing prefix?.

I know the way where I can get the value by passing index but may be tomorrow index can get change so is it possible to fetch the value by passing prefix?

Comment: Iterate through the array(s) and check whether the entry `startsWith` or `contains` `"AA"`?

Answer (score 1):

In case OP wants a function to do this.

```js
function(arr, pattern){
  return arr.map(function(x){
    return x.filter( word => ~ word.indexOf(pattern))
  });    
}
```

```js
var arr = 
[ [ "Django UnChainers", "AA-24010" ], [ "General", "AA-26191" ]];

var list = arr.map(function(x){
  if(~(x[1].indexOf('AA'))){
    return x[1];
  }
});

console.log(list);
```

In case the index changes in future, iterate through each string and check for the "AA" string. Check the below code.

```js
var arr = 
    [ [ "Django UnChainers", "AA-24010" ], [ "General", "AA-26191" ]];

    var list = arr.map(function(x){
      return x.filter( word => ~ word.indexOf('AA'))
    });

    console.log(list);
```

Comment: *but may be tomorrow index can get change*

Comment: In that case we have to iterate through each element in the array, which won't be a problem.

Comment: *which won't be a problem* - prove it

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just make it a function and extract the argument, it's really not a lot of magic.

Answer (score 1):

this is shorter

```
var = [nested array]
a.filter(x => x[1].startsWith('AA'))
//in case you are not sure about the index 
a.filter(x => x.filter(y => y.startsWith('AA').length > 0))
```

Comment: *but may be tomorrow index can get change*

Comment: I have added which will increase the running time but if the index change it will not be affected.